# How to read in plain english `map: <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (ma: M<A>) => M<B>`

Tags: typescript

Could you please help me to understand the meaning of this interface in typescript?

For my understanding when this interface is applied... an object must implement a function named `map` not sure what `<A, B>` means here.

If you could provide me a plain English "translation" I would really appreciate it.

```
interface Functor<M> {
    map: <A, B>(f: (a: A) => B) => (ma: M<A>) => M<B>
}
```

Comment: The `<A, B>` are type parameters (aka generics). [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Answer (score 1):

This interface (currently) isn't valid in TypeScript because TypeScript does not support [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), but the intent is still clear.

`M` represents a generic data structure, such as `Array` or `Set`, that can be parameterized with a given type to hold elements of that type (for example, `Array<number>` or `Set<string>`).  Let's take `M = Array` as an example.  A `Functor<Array>` implementation takes an array of elements of one type `A`  (`Array<A>` or `A[]`) and translates each element to type `B` using a provided function `f: (a: A) => B`; the result is an array of elements of type `B` (`Array<B>` or `B[]`).  This transformation is possible for any types `A` and `B` as long as you have an appropriate function `f: (a: A) => B` to translate the individual elements; that's why `map` is generic in `A` and `B`.  And in fact, one would assume a `Functor<Array>` would be implemented using the equivalent of `Array.prototype.map`.  A `Functor<Set>` would be the same idea, except it translates a `Set<A>` to a `Set<B>`.

I hope this explains the TypeScript angle.  For introductions of functors in general, I did [a quick web search](https://www.google.com/search?q=functor+functional+programming+introduction) and found two that look helpful ([1](https://medium.com/@dtinth/what-is-a-functor-dcf510b098b6), [2](https://medium.com/@JosephJnk/a-short-introduction-to-functors-e252c1e3768f)).